# How to create custom bindings syntax for Hogan.js (unescaped HTML version)

Tags: javascript, mustache, hogan.js

I'm currently doing

```
var compiledHtml = Hogan.compile(templateHtml, { delimiters: '<% %>' });
```

This works great. But I need to output some HTML, usually I could use mustache default `{{{`, how can I achieve this with my custom syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using non-standard delimiters, you should still be able to use `&` for unescaped tags. This:

```
<% thing %>
<%& thing %>
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
{{ thing }}
{{{ thing }}}
```